# JRI for c++ , can't figure our method signature

Tags: java, visual-studio-2010, jri

I'm using JRI inside visual studio 2012, and I'm calling this function:

```
jmethodID jmMainMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(jcJclass, "loadModel", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
```

The actual function in javascript is something like this:

```
var lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(@"C:\englishPCFG.ser.gz");
```

It is static type class, which gets string parameter, and return object of type LexicalizedParse.

This is wrong method signature I am using right now: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
How to figure correct one? I could only google examples for string, floats, integers, but what if I have custom type lile I do with LexicalizedParse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an example in your question.

```
java.lang.String
```

becomes

```
Ljava/lang/String;
```

so

```
mypackage.LexicalizedParse
```

becomes

```
Lmypackage/LexicalizedParse;
```

`V` mean `void` so this is not the correct return type.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll figure out from there.